# MongoDB UpdateMany Where One or More Array Items Aren't In Provided List

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    "Tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2"
    ]
    "SubCollection": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("55849c0002cee826cc67550a"),
        "Timestamp": NumberLong(635703508937961307)
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
        "Timestamp": NumberLong(635703508937961307)
    }]  
}

    public class RootEntity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
        public List<SubEntity> SubCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubEntity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to create a mongo update that removes a subcollection entity if the document has any tags that aren't in a provided tag list.

It looks to me like the update below should work but when I test it I get an IndexOutOfRangeException when calling UpdateManyAsync.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Can anyone help me figure out why this doesn't work?  Please note that I am using the C# .NET MongoDB Driver v2.0:

```
    public async Task Test(ObjectId subEntityId, List<string> providedTags)
    {
        var subEntityIsInTheSubCollection = Builders<RootEntity>.Filter
            .ElemMatch(x => x.SubCollection, subEntity => subEntity.Id == subEntityId);

        var entityContainsTagsThatArentInProvidedList = Builders<RootEntity>.Filter
            .Where(root => root.Tags.Any(x => !providedTags.Contains(x)));

        var filter = Builders<RootEntity>.Filter.And(
            subEntityIsInTheSubCollection,
            entityContainsTagsThatArentInProvidedList);

        var update = Builders<RootEntity>.Update
            .PullFilter(x => x.SubCollection, subEntity => subEntity.Id == subEntityId);

        await _collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
    }
```

I've created a sample project to reproduce the bug which can be found here.
https://github.com/nickmkk/UpdateWhereItemsArentInProvidedList

Run the tests in RemoveSubEntityServiceTests.cs to reproduce the issue.

Note that the problem seems to be with the filter in RemoveSubEntityService.cs on line 25

Comment: I'm thinking this may be a mongo csharp driver bug.  I've created a bug ticket for this issue and will see what they say.  

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1356

Comment: This basically looks like you want either `{ "Tags": { "$not": { "$all": ["tag1","tag2"] } } }` or `{ "Tags": { "$nin": ["tag1","tag2"] } }` depending on whether you want either "both" or "either" tag values, respectively to exclude from a match in your "Tags" portion. Not sure of the lamda syntax for that first statement though without a current environment to test in.